Cannot install godot plugin on rider 2024.2.7
I`m trying to install godot plugin from the disk, and it gives this error message:

Plugin 'Godot Support' (version '2024.1.171') is not compatible with the current version of the IDE, because it requires build 241.* or older but the current build is RD-242.23726.100

It's a fresh install of Rider, there is no plugin installed. I'm following this tutorial: https://www.jetbrains.com/guide/gamedev/tutorials/rider-godot-pong/dev-environment-setup/
I`ve tried to reinstall Rider, but it keeps giving the same result

From the plugin page: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13882-godot-support

Starting with Rider 2024.2, this plugin is now bundled with the
software.
As a result, no further updates will be published on the Marketplace.
Adds support for the Godot engine.

